# Lambda expression for showing table status

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda

I am using ASP.NET Core & Entity Framework Core. How can I write this query as a lambda expression or linq?

```
show table status WHERE NAME = 'crm_Pipeline';
```

Comment: What did you try? What is the type of your input source?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Your only option to execute it is to write:

```
_context.Database.SqlQuery<Status>("show table status WHERE NAME = 'crm_Pipeline'");
```

And you need to declare the status class that covers the result.